# Representing multiple headers to single cell

Tags: excel, vba

Goal: Have the column header of any text in red from multiple cells be represented in column F of the same row as the text.

Problem: Current code copies header cells and pastes them over each other if multiple cells in the same row contain red text. Would rather have the header text copied, and added to any other text in that cell.

My previous question was answered (Thanks SJR!), but it was a flawed concept. Instead of copying the cells in question, I suppose I really need a way to copy the text and separate each instance with a comma. The general idea is that the red text that the module is looking for are changes made to a worksheet, and the cells I'm trying to populate are the summaries of what type of changes were made, with the type being the headers of each column.

```
Sub CopyRed()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("G3:BF900")

For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells
        If cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Cells(2, cell.Column).Copy Range("F" & cell.row)
        End If
    Next cell
Next row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Sub CopyRed()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("G3:BF900")
For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells
        For i = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
            If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed and cell.value <> "" Then
                If Cells(cell.row, 6) = "" Then
                    Cells(cell.row, 6).Value = Cells(2, cell.Column).Value
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Cells(cell.row, 6).Value = Cells(cell.row, 6).Value & ", " & Cells(2, cell.Column).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next cell
Next row
End Sub
```

Comment: This takes care of most of the functionality, but I just realized that this code looks for the active font color of the cell, and not if any text of that font color is present. Any idea how to change that?

Comment: updated it. `if cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 and cell.value <> "" then`, but this is even safer. only add header to column f, if the whole text in the cell is red.

Comment: Understood that it currently works if the whole cell is red, and that does satisfy a lot of my problems. Is there any way to check if any character in the cell is red? 

Thanks for your time so far btw, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is possible, but that would mean to go trough every character of each cell and that could make the runtime pretty bad.

Comment: That's ultimately what I'm looking for, even if the run time is bad.

Comment: it should do the job now :)

Comment: You're amazing!